# Android Launching Map Activity takes long

Tags: android, google-maps

Ive created an app which loads a map with allot of extra content put into the map.

The app takes a while to start up and resume because of all the content.

What are my options for letting the user know the app isnt frozen?

Ive thought of using a progress dialog while the map loads but have been unsuccessful in getting it working.

Also read that you can show the grey blocks of the map while the other content loads. How do I do this?

What would be the best solution?

Regards
Jared

Comment: To help you with optimizations, would you mind posting some code? Perhaps we can even help you get that ProgressBar working.

Comment: before we can suggest anything we would need to see what you are doing

Comment: i suggest adding a map callback https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback.html (use this when to close a progressbar) . by the way this is only for the map when it finished rendering(not the extra content).

Answer (score -1):

Here are the ways I know in which you can do this:

1. Use a thread and start loading the map as soon as the app begins and do other things in the app's main thread.
2. Use a service:  Create a service which constantly runs in the background even when the user is not using the app. And use this service to maintain the maps in the background.

Refer vogella, they have very good tutorials for both threads and services. ALL THE BEST